# store secrets in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net-maui

I'm meddling around with .net MAUI a bit. I'm trying to figure out where to store an api key. In android studio I would create a secrets.xml in the resources folder and add that file to the .gitignore. For some reason I cannot find how to do this in .net MAUI. What is the normal way here to deal with secrets that you do not want in the .git but do need to end up in the compiled code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly save your secrete into local storage without putting it into a code. You need to fetch it from somewhere via some API call.

There are two ways:

1. Use [Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview) to store such secretes and fetch these secretes using Azure Functions. Steps for Xamarin.Forms app given [here](https://codemilltech.com/mobile-apps-azure-keyvault-dont-do-it/). And same applies for .NET Maui app too.
   NOTE: We must use Azure Functions to read secretes from KeyVault and provide them in response. Mobile app should call this function endpoint to get secretes we need from KeyVault.
   Azure KeyVault is not free of cost. Check prizing [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/key-vault/#pricing).
2. Create an API which gives you this subscription key in response as encrypted format. This API should not be authenticated API and should work without any Token, means you should encrypt your response for security concerns.
   Then make a call to this API in your mobile app and decrypt it and use it where you need.

Comment: But then you have a unauthenticated API exposing your secrets, that doesn't seem right.. Isn't there another route?

Comment: I mentioned to encrypt a response rather than plain json or string response and then decrypt the response.

Comment: And where would you store the decryption key?

Comment: I think keep Enc. Dec. key in Constant file, then use Dotfuscator tool to obfuscate your source code to protect apk/aab or ipa file from reverse engineering. If you want the secretes accessed even before authentication, then this is the only way I know. If you find any other way, happy to know it. Thanks.

Comment: Hm that could do the trick, but sounds a bit hacky to me... Thanks for your answers btw, I am new to mobile dev and am curious how to properly solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Store secrets in compiled code is not safe.
Your app should get the API Key from a safe server. After getting the key, you can use Secure Storage to store the key locally.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android

Comment: Hello RenanStr - we have an API subscription key that we require in the headers, along with the oAuth token for the API.  What would be the best approach to get that API subscription key in the secret storage?

Comment: string apiKey = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("api_subscription_key");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api_key", apiKey);

Comment: Yes, I get that :). The question was more on how to initially get it there, and avoid it can get leaked (so not baking it in the source code, not retrieving it from a public url, etc)

Comment: @SamVanhoutte I have the same issue, how did you resolve this?  I get the no passwords in source or compiled code.  They can be stored safely in the secure storage, but how to get them into the secure storage on the users devices, that I do not have access to, without giving them to the users to enter?

Comment: I did not (yet?) solve this, unfortunately

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is the .gitignore file too, just you need to manually open the top folder in the File explorer to see it.

Also you can use conditional compiling in the code like:

```
#if DEBUG
mysecrect = "mysecrect";
#endif
```